# Photos in html Email keeps cutting off

Tags: html, html-email

[html siganture keeps cutting off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLaNF.png)

I have 0 html experience but can edit code if its straightforward enough.
The top of my logo/social media icons keeps cutting off on outlook. They don't cut off when I open the email in a browser or through a mobile device. Is there a way to edit the code so that it doesn't cut off? I tried adding padding to the top but it doesn't work. Please help.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnAbj.jpg)

```
<table width="335" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"> <tr> <td style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0;"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"> <tr> <td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 2px; color: #515151; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:15px;"> <b>Ryan Milliman </b> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 6px; color: #515151; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:15px;"> <b> <small style="color:#515151;" >Director of Investor Relations</small></b> </td> </tr>  <tr> <td colspan="2" style="color: #333333; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:6px;line-height:0px;"> <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/border.png" width="333" height="3" alt="" /> </td> </tr>  <tr> <td  valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4px;line-height:15px;"> <b style="color:#9d1924;" >O:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="tel:(800) 735- 9973" style=" color: #384241; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px;">(800) 735- 9973</a> </td> <td  valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4px;line-height:15px;"> <b style="color:#9d1924;">M:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="tel:(760) 793- 2933" style=" color: #384241; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px;">(760) 793- 2933</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td> </tr>  <tr> <td  valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4px;line-height:15px;"> <b style="color:#9d1924;" >W:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.primior.com" style=" color: #384241; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px;">www.primior.com</a> </td> <td  valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4px;line-height:15px;"> <b style="color:#9d1924;">E:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:ryan.milliman@primior.com" style=" color: #384241; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px;">ryan.milliman@primior.com</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td> </tr>  <tr> <td colspan="2" style="color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:6px;"> <b style="color:#9d1924;">A:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://goo.gl/maps/PpK3QXkHhoTpySej9" style="text-decoration:none;color:#384241;" >750 N Diamond Bar Blvd, Ste 188, Diamond Bar,CA 91765</a> </td> </tr>  <tr> <td colspan="2" style="color: #333333; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:6px;line-height:0px;"> <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/border.png" width="333" height="3" alt="" /> </td> </tr>   <tr> <td  valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:7px; padding-top:7px;line-height:15px;"> <a href="http://www.primior.com"> <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/logo.png" width="155" height="20" alt="" /> </a> </td> <td  valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #384241; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px;line-height:15px;text-align:right;">   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PrimiorGroup/" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;color: #464444;"><img width="20" height="20" style="border: none; width: 20px; max-width: 20px !important; height: 20px; max-height: 20px !important;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/fb.png"></a> &nbsp; <a href="https://twitter.com/Primior_Inc" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;color: #464444;"><img width="20" height="20" style="border: none; width: 20px; max-width: 20px !important; height: 20px; max-height: 20px !important;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/tw.png"></a> &nbsp; <a href="https://www.instagram.com/primior_inc/" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;color: #464444;"><img width="20" height="20" style="border: none; width: 20px; max-width: 20px !important; height: 20px; max-height: 20px !important;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/lin.png"></a> &nbsp; <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/primior-inc./ " style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;color: #464444;"><img width="20" height="20" style="border: none; width: 20px; max-width: 20px !important; height: 20px; max-height: 20px !important;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/riya1/image/upload/v1563430617/SIN311/ins.png"></a>   </td> </tr>   </table> </td> </tr>  </table>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code rather than screenshotting it? There are tools here that allow you to paste code, please use it. It helps us diagnose, reproduce and help fix it. Reading code in that state isn't helping you or us.

Comment: Sorry, even asking a question was confusing to me

Comment: I added my code if you are down to help.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook sometimes ignores the width/height of an element.
Try adding width and height to your td where the Image is located.